# SharePoint Online Alternative to Tag Cloud

Tags: sharepoint-online

Tags are deprecated in SharePoint online. However, we can use Enterprise Keyword Column. And searching by this works too. But how do I display list of all enterprise keyword columns? Like tag cloud. Where user can get list of keywords created and clicking on it will display all documents where the selected enterprise keyword is added.